# EPub Spell Checker using Jazzy (Word with wrong spelling doesn't appear in JTable) - Closed

Tags: java, netbeans, spell-checking, epub

I created an EPub Spell Checker using Jazzy Spell Library. The problem is whenever I run my built project, the word with spelling error should appear in the JTable but is doesn't appear in the JTable. I tried to run the project on the IDE and it works. What do you think is the problem?

**Here is the code for spell check**

---

```
private void btnSpellActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                         
    try {
        this.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR);
        File dic = new File(new File(strTmp,"dic"), cboDictionary.getSelectedItem().toString());
        SpellDictionary dict = new SpellDictionaryHashMap(dic);
        SpellProc p = new SpellProc();

        DataCls dc = new DataCls();
        dc.ExeComm("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblError;"
            + "CREATE TABLE tblError("
                + "FILE VARCHAR(255), "
                + "WORD VARCHAR(255), "
                + "LINE INT(10)"
                + ")");
        String[] col = new String[]{"File","Word","Line"};
        p.dtm.addColumn(col[0]);
        p.dtm.addColumn(col[1]);
        p.dtm.addColumn(col[2]);
        for(int i = 0; i < lstFile.getSize(); i++) {
            SpellChecker splChkr = new SpellChecker(dict);
            spellCheck splChk = p.new spellCheck();
            splChk.file = lstFile.getElementAt(i).toString();
            splChk.counter = 0;
            splChkr.addSpellCheckListener(splChk);
            String toCheck = p.readXHTML(new File(lstFile.getElementAt(i).toString()));
            splChkr.checkSpelling(new StringWordTokenizer(toCheck));
        }
        ResultSet rs = dc.ExeQuery("SELECT * FROM tblError");
        try {
            while (rs.next()) {
                String cont[] = new String[rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount()];
                for (int i = 0; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    cont[i] = rs.getString(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1).toString());
                }
                p.dtm.addRow(cont);
            }
            rs.close();
            tblView.setModel(p.dtm);
        }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e);
    }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Spell checking completed.");
        this.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR);
    } 
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "File loading error. \r\n\r\n" + e, "Error Occured.", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    } 
    catch(IOException f) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "File loading error. \r\n\r\n" + f, "Error Occured.", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

---

**Here is the code for spellCheck();**

---

```
public class spellCheck implements SpellCheckListener {
    String file = "";
    String lst = "";
    String[] rValue = {"","",""};
    int counter;
    String find = "";
    DataCls dat = new DataCls();
    @Override
    public void spellingError(SpellCheckEvent svt) {

        lst ="";
        lstError.addElement(svt.getInvalidWord().replace("'", "\\'"));

        try {
            ResultSet rChk = dat.ExeQuery("SELECT MAX(LINE) FROM tblError WHERE FILE='" + new File(file).getName() + "'AND WORD='" + svt.getInvalidWord().replace("'", "''") + "'");
            int rwCnt = 0;
            while(rChk.next()) {rwCnt++;}
            if (rwCnt == 0) {
                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    int i = 0;
                    String line;
                    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        i++;
                        int index = line.indexOf(svt.getInvalidWord().replace("'", "\\'"));
                        if (index >= 0) {
                            dat.ExeComm("INSERT INTO tblError(FILE,WORD,LINE) "
                                    + "VALUES ('" + new File(file).getName() +"','" + svt.getInvalidWord().replace("'", "\\'") + "','" + i + "')");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                }

            } else if (rwCnt > 0){
                ResultSet rs = dat.ExeQuery("SELECT MAX(LINE) FROM tblError WHERE FILE='" + new File(file).getName() + "' AND WORD='" + svt.getInvalidWord().replace("'", "''") + "'");
                rs.next();
                try {
                        int iline = rs.getInt(1);
                        try {
                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                            int i = 0;
                            String line;
                            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                                i++;
                                int index = line.indexOf(svt.getInvalidWord().replace("'", "\\'"));
                                if (i > iline) {
                                    if (index >= 0) {
                                        dat.ExeComm("INSERT INTO tblError(FILE,WORD,LINE) "
                                                + "VALUES ('" + new File(file).getName() +"','" + svt.getInvalidWord().replace("'", "\\'") + "','" + i + "')");
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        catch (IOException e) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                        }
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @JaneDoe I have posted the code.